# Can $0 \preceq A\preceq B$ and $span(A)\subseteq span(B)$ lead to $\sigma_i(A)\leq \sigma_i(B)$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Can $0 \preceq A\preceq B$ and $span(A)\subseteq span(B)$ lead to $\sigma_i(A)\leq \sigma_i(B)$?

In the question, $A\preceq B$ means that $B-A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, $span(A)\subseteq span(B)$ means that the column space of $A$ belongs to the column space of $B$, and $\sigma_i(\cdot)$ means the $i$-th largest singular value.

Moreover, I am not sure if $span(A)\subseteq span(B)$  is necessary or not.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This follows from Courant-Fischer minimax principle. The span condition is indeed redundant.

Comment: @user1551 it works, thanks very much.